# Passing data into a partial

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to pass an array of data into a partial, this partial is then being called from another view.

```
$posts = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three"
]; 

return View::make('partials.post_template', $posts);
```

Inside the `.blade.php`file I am then doing

```
{{$posts}}
```

This returns and error of `Undefined variable: posts` Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The laravel manual suggests a different writing: `View::make('partials.post_template', array('posts' => $posts));` - And do you understand what undefined variable means? If so, what don't you understand you're doing wrong so far with such error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The template you're using contains an undefined variable, here named *posts*.

It is important that you define all variables you intend to use with a view.

You pass such variables in form of an array where the key is the name of the variable and the value is the data that variable carries:

```
View::make('template-with-posts-variable', array('posts' => $posts));
```

It is the second parameter. The first parameter is the name of the template.

Comment: Same error I'm afraid. Is this because I am passing this to a partial?

Comment: Well, you're having a sub-view then and you don't specify the variable for the subview. The error will not go away unless you define that variable for the view that has that variable (not for a different one).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does not send your variable as `posts`. If you have an array:

```
$data = [
    'posts' => [
        'One' => '1',
        'Two' => '2',
        'Three' => '3',
    ],
];
```

Then if you pass this data as you do pass `$posts` you will be able to access `posts` variable inside the view.

See [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a variable and pass it data like so

```
return View::make('partials.post_template')
    ->with('posts', $posts);

// or
return View::make('partials.post_template'
    ->withPosts($posts); // with a magic method
```

For more info see the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)

Comment: Still getting an undefined error when trying to call $posts in the view.

Comment: Well, the syntax suggested in this answer is not by the book as well, which could be also cause of the problem.

Comment: @hakre What do you mean, it's officially supported, see "Passing Data To Views" on the docs

Comment: @afarazit: Yes exactly that part. The code in your answer looks like a mesh up of the different ways to do say mixed together. I don't think Laravel is that mature that this works that easily.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 just spotted my error, try the code again.

Comment: sad thing is, this will give the same error. posts will be defined then, but the error remains, so it's in a different template.